# Can I use sudo in Ansible with connection "local"?

Tags: ansible

I give up, just can't understand how to use Ansible with "connection: local" + "sudo: yes".
I have something like:

```
ansible-playbook ansible/desktop.yml

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  ...
  tasks:
    - apt_repository: repo='ppa:alexey-smirnov/deadbeef'
      sudo: yes
```

I've also tried `sudo_user: ...` param, `sudo` before the command, `ansible-playbook --sudo` and `--ask-sudo-pass`

Currently:

```
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true}
msg: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

How should it be executed?

```
ansible --version
ansible 1.7.2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44905691/217408 worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
ansible-playbook -i <inventory> ansible/desktop.yml -u <local user who can sudo with password> --ask-sudo-pass
```

This will make ansible use the remote user you mentioned in `-u`. And when it uses that user to sudo, it will ask you for sudo password.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method (also works with ansible `become:` syntax):

`sudo su -c "ansible-playbook <your playbook name and options>"`