# Using --become for ansible_connection=local

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

With a personal user account (userx) I run the ansible playbook on all my specified hosts. In ansible.cfg the remote user (which can become root) to be used is:

```
remote_user = ansible
```

For the remote hosts this all works fine. It connects as the user Ansible, and executes all tasks as wished for, also changing information (like `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) which requires root rights.

But now I also want to execute the playbook on the Ansible host itself. I put the following in my inventory file:

```
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

which now indeed executes on localhost. But as userx, and this results in "Access denied" for some task it needs to do.

This is of course somewhat expected, since remote_user tells something about *remote*, not the local user. But still, I expected that the playbook would `--become` locally too, to execute the tasks as root (e.g. `sudo su -`). It seems no to do that.

Running the playbook with `--become -vvv` tells me

```
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: userx
```

and it seems not to try to execute the tasks with sudo. And without using sudo, the task fails.

How can I tell ansible to to use sudo / become on the local connection too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing special is required. Proof:

- The playbook:

  ```
  ---
  - hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no
    connection: local
    tasks:
      - command: whoami
        register: whoami
      - debug:
          var: whoami.stdout
  ```
- The execution line:

  ```
  ansible-playbook playbook.yml --become
  ```
- The result:

  ```
  PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************

  TASK [command] *****************************************************************************************************
  changed: [localhost]

  TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "changed": false,
      "whoami.stdout": "root"
  }

  PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
  ```

---

The `ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER:` message will always show the current user, as it the account used "to connect".

Later the command(s) called from the module get(s) executed with elevated permissions.

---

Of course, you can add `become: yes` on either play level or for individual tasks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing proof. It helped me finding the real issues: The remotes worked, because they logged in as the `ansible` user, which had the correct rights. Locally, the specific task needed `become`. I tried to specify this at the inventory-file level, but misused `ansible_become` by setting it to `=ansible` (evaluates to false). And then the inventory file has precedence over the command-line `--become`, which finally led to a failing task.